# In React, if a state is an empty array then how do you render a text conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, conditional-statements

I want to render 'menu is empty'. Otherwise I am able to map through and render the json data from the api correctly.

```
const Navbar = () => {
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);

    if (menu === []) {
        setMenu(["menu is empty"])
    }

    return (
        <div className='nav-area'>
        <Link to='/' className='logo'>LOGO</Link>
            <ul className='menus'>
            {menu.map((main) => (
            <MenuItems items={main} key={main.type}/>
            ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check your array length and base on that render text or ul with items

sth like this :

```
const Navbar = () => {
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);


    return (
        <div className='nav-area'>
        <Link to='/' className='logo'>LOGO</Link>
        {
              menu.length > 0 ? (
                <ul className='menus'>
  
           {
              menu.map((main) => (
                <MenuItems items={main} key={main.type}/>
                )) 
            }
           
            </ul>
              )  : <>menu is empty</>
          }
           
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: You should explain how you've solved the problem/what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline If-Else to render conditionally.

[Inline If-Else with Conditional Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)

Example:

```
const Navbar = () => {
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);

    if (menu === []) {
        setMenu(["menu is empty"])
    }

    return (
        <div className='nav-area'>
        <Link to='/' className='logo'>LOGO</Link>
            <ul className='menus'>
            { menu.lenght < 1
                  ? menu.map((main) => (
                        <MenuItems items={main} key={main.type}/>
                    ))
                  : 'menu is empty'
             }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario there is two possibilities either menu is empty or have some data.

What i do in this situation is check for condition whether array is empty by `.length` property and also check for if not empty then is it an array or not by `Array.isArray` method.

If both condition satisfy then render the content otherwise render the "Menu is empty".
Something like this

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="nav-area">
      <Link to="/" className="logo">
        LOGO
      </Link>

      {Array.isArray(menu) && menu.length ? (
        <ul className="menus">
          {menu.map((main) => (
            <MenuItem items={main} key={main.type} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : (
       // or you may have a component for this 
        <h3>Menu is Empty</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

right way using react

```
import { useMemo } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);

    const displayMenus = useMemo(
        () =>
        {
            if(menu.length === 0) return <div>EMPTY</div>
            return menu.map(
                (main) =>
                {
                    return <MenuItems items={main} key={main.type}/>
                }
            )
        },
        [menu]
    )

    return (
        <div className='nav-area'>
            <Link to='/' className='logo'>LOGO</Link>
            <ul className='menus'>
                {displayMenus}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```